# Work flow of simpleFormcontroller in spring MVC 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have seen many examples on how `simpleFormcontroller` works.

But still I have some confusion.

I want to know when `formBackingObject()`, `referenceData()`, `onSubmit()` methods invoked?

I dont know exact working flow of these methods?

Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SimpleFormController` is deprecated since Spring 3.0

In Spring 3.0 use one controller with two methods for the creation process (and a third one for the show page). It typical looks like that:

```
/**
 * Shows a form for car creation.
 */
@RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createForm() {
    ModelMap uiModel = new ModelMap();
    uiModel.addAttribute("carCreateFormBackingObject", new CarCreateFormBackingObject()); //formBackingObject - often called command object
    uiModel.addAttribute("manufactureres", this.manufactureresDao.readAll()); //referenceData
    return new ModelAndView("car/create", uiModel);
}

/**
 * Creates the car and redirects to its detail page.
 *
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(final @Valid CarCreateFormBackingObject carCreateFormBackingObject,
        final BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                ModelMap uiModel = new ModelMap();
        uiModel.addAttribute("carCreateFormBackingObject", carCreateFormBackingObject);
        uiModel.addAttribute("manufactureres", this.manufactureresDao.readAll()); //referenceData
        return new ModelAndView("car/create", uiModel);
    }

    Car car = this.carService.create(carCreateFormBackingObject.name, ...);
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/cars/" + car.getId(), true)); //redirect to show page
}
```

---

**still i want to know formBackingObject(),refernceData() method get invoked automatically by whom and when?**

Back to your question "still i want to know formBackingObject(),refernceData() method get invoked automatically by whom and when?"

All these methods get invoked by `SimpleFormController` (and its superclass `AbstractFormController`), the follow the Template-Method-Pattern. - `SimpleFormController` defines the process and your concrete subclass "plugsin" in some hooks of this process to gain the business value.

- `formBackingObject` in invoked by `AbstractFormController` when the controller needs to handle a Submit (POST), or build the Command object for the initial "new" view.
- `referenceData` is always invoked `AbstractFormController` when it need to build the model for the view.

Answer (score 12):

Workflow is as follows and it is controlled by `AbstractFormController` class-

> 1. The controller receives a request for a new form (typically a **GET**).
> 2. Call to **formBackingObject()** which by default, returns an instance of the **commandClass** that has been configured (see the properties the superclass exposes), but can also be overridden to e.g. retrieve an object from the database (that needs to be modified using the form).
> 3. Call to **initBinder()** which allows you to register custom editors for certain fields (often properties of non-primitive or non-String types) of the command class. This will render appropriate Strings for those property values, e.g. locale-specific date strings.
> 4. Only if bindOnNewForm is set to true, then ServletRequestDataBinder gets applied to populate the new form object with initial request parameters and the **onBindOnNewForm(HttpServletRequest, Object, BindException)** callback method is called. Note: any defined Validators are not applied at this point, to allow partial binding. However be aware that any Binder customizations applied via **initBinder()** (such as DataBinder.setRequiredFields(String[]) will still apply. As such, if using bindOnNewForm=true and initBinder() customizations are used to validate fields instead of using Validators, in the case that only some fields will be populated for the new form, there will potentially be some bind errors for missing fields in the errors object. Any view (JSP, etc.) that displays binder errors needs to be intelligent and for this case take into account whether it is displaying the initial form view or subsequent post results, skipping error display for the former.
> 5. Call to **showForm()** to return a View that should be rendered (typically the view that renders the form). This method has to be implemented in subclasses.
> 6. The **showForm()** implementation will call **referenceData()**, which you can implement to provide any relevant reference data you might need when editing a form (e.g. a List of Locale objects you're going to let the user select one from).
> 7. Model gets exposed and view gets rendered, to let the user fill in the form.
> 8. The controller receives a form submission (typically a POST). To use a different way of detecting a form submission, override the **isFormSubmission** method.
> 9. If **sessionForm** is not set, **formBackingObject()** is called to retrieve a form object. Otherwise, the controller tries to find the command object which is already bound in the session. If it cannot find the object, it does a call to **handleInvalidSubmit** which - by default - tries to create a new form object and resubmit the form.
> 10. The **ServletRequestDataBinder** gets applied to populate the form object with current request parameters.
> 11. Call to **onBind(HttpServletRequest, Object, Errors)** which allows you to do custom processing after binding but before validation (e.g. to manually bind request parameters to bean properties, to be seen by the Validator).
> 12. If validateOnBinding is set, a registered Validator will be invoked. The Validator will check the form object properties, and register corresponding errors via the given Errors object.
> 13. Call to **onBindAndValidate()** which allows you to do custom processing after binding and validation (e.g. to manually bind request parameters, and to validate them outside a Validator).
> 14. Call **processFormSubmission()** to process the submission, with or without binding errors. This method has to be implemented in subclasses.

[Source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractFormController.html#workflow)

For more details and diagrammatic representation to understand the flow you can refer to below link -

Answer (score 1):

**formBackingObject()** method, is used when you want to take some action before rendering page. i.e. like default value in HTML components.

**refereceData()** method, is used for add reference data in your form, i.e. populating dropdowns

**OnSubmit()** method, is called whe you submit form.

But, if you are using Spring 3.0
Follow following approach using annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLogin() {
    return "user/login";
}
```

This will same as formBackingObject. and in this method use modelMap() and add reference data.

Add methods same way with method = POST which will be same as OnSubmit()

Comment: Hi Vinit,thanks for your answer.still i want to know formBackingObject(),refernceData() method get invoked automatically by whom and when?

Answer (score 0):

rfe folling link

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html

Read Workflow.. you can simply understand your doubts..

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: "target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future" - so we should paste all we need to SO =) Also MSDN complete =)

Answer (score 0):

FormBackingObjectMethod()---> @RequestMapping(requestMethod.GET)
while first time form shown to the screen formBackingObject is the reason

initBinder()---> normally used for suppose you want date field should be for example (custom date example : dd**MM***yyyy) needed means use initBinder method

onSubmit() -->@RequestMapping(requestMethod.POST)
 while submitting the form onSubmit() method get called

i hope this helps